# In itunes 10, where is the " Store Full Resolution Photos" option?

Tags: itunes, ipod-touch, data-synchronization, photos

I can't seem to find this option any more.  has it moved ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently it has been **re**moved according to a [discussion on Apple's forums](http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=2186066)